# Why don't the app run under Android 4.x in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is a very simple app made by Kotlin, it can work well under Android 8.0,  Android 6.0 and Android 5.1 in Android Studio 3.0

but I get the error message "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.dodata.mirror/ui.UIMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ui.UIMain" when I run the app under Android 4.1. 2 (This is a real mobile phone) and Android 4.2.2

You can test it by download the app at https://www.dropbox.com/s/9f0yxp5pqqxtcxq/Mirror.zip?dl=0

[image]

**UIMain.kt**

```
package ui
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import info.dodata.mirror.R
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.mirror">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="ui.UIMain">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        applicationId "info.dodata.mirror"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.01"
        archivesBaseName = "BackupSettings-V" + versionName
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.mirror"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.mirror.pro"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "false"
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IsDebugMode", "true"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
}
```

**build.gradle (Top)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.2'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Android 5.0 and later, multiple .dex files are automatically loaded by ART together. However, on earlier Android versions, Dalvik starts the application with only the main classes.dex, and the application must load the secondary the .dex files before anything else is done.

This is handled by the multidex support library, but you did not follow the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle). This means that some of your classes are not present when the system is trying to start your activity, leading to a crash.

> Depending on whether you override the `Application` class, perform one of the following:
>
> - If you do not override the `Application` class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the `<application>` tag as follows:
>
>   ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.example.myapp">
>       <application
>               android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
>           ...
>       </application>
>   </manifest>
>   ```
> - If you do override the `Application` class, change it to extend `MultiDexApplication` (if possible) as follows:
>
>   ```
>   public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
>   ```
> - Or if you do override the `Application` class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable multidex:
>
>   ```
>   public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
>     @Override
>     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
>        super.attachBaseContext(base);
>        MultiDex.install(this);
>     }
>   }
>   ```

You are currently not overriding `Application`, so you should follow the first case.

Comment: Thanks! The app crash yet after I add  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: The app can work well under Android 4.0 after I delete both  multiDexEnabled true and  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

Comment: @HelloCW If your app is small enough that multidex is not necessary, then go ahead and remove it. Build times will be faster too.